# Find logged in user's pst files and copy to back up location in vbs

Tags: batch-file, outlook, vbscript, pst

I am trying to convert the following batch into vbs.. anyhelp would be much appreciated. ====>

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a IN (%userprofile%\out.txt) DO (
 xcopy "%%a" H:\PST-Backup\
 )
```

Comment: this is what i came up with so far that doesnt work..                                               WshShell.run "%comspec% /c FOR /F ""tokens=1 delims="" %a IN (%userprofile%\pst-file-list.txt) DO xcopy /y %a ""H:\PST-Backup\""", 0, True

Comment: I'm guessing that this batch works for you.
And you just use a vbscript to hide the console i'm right ?

Comment: i basically want a vbs that will close outlook, find all the the logged in users pst's, copy them to their home drive, then re-open outlook. i got most of it done but the copying the pst file.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a user can have multiple profiles with multiple PST files that can be located in any folder.

If you are only interested in the active/default profile, use `Namespace.Stores` collection and use the `Store.FilePath` property to figure out the PST file location. Keep in mind that OOM will give you both OST and PST file paths, so you would need to filter out OSTs.

To read the PST file paths from all Outlook profiles (as shown at Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles), you can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) and the profile management API ([IProfAdmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815345.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) etc.) or you can use the [ProfMan](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) library (any language, I am its author) - see an example that does exactly what you need at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example2